# EF6 Complaining that unused Model has no Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I just spent some time resolving the strangest bug, and I can't figure out why it happened.  Maybe someone can follow along and shed some light on why...?

**tl;dr:** lightweight MembershipContext fails due to some completely unrelated object not having and ID field, but only does so when running under MVC: all integration tests that make sure this stuff works correctly... they work correctly.

**What I Have:**

I have a solution with a number of projects.  The pertinent ones are:

- LPA.Domain (contains POCOs for business objects/behavior)
- LPA.Data   (contains EF6 stuff with FluentAPI config and references LPA.Domain)
- LPA.Web    (contains an MVC project, refs Data and Domain)

This is a very normal setup for us and the project has been in development for some time with no issues.

Within the Data project I have two DbContexts that are used.  One, `MembershipContext` is used only during login and bypasses the user-based audit system to validate the user.  The `MembershipContext` has only three entities: User, UserMembershipDetail and UserRole.

The second, `CoreContext` has all the normal stuff (including tracking the currently logged in user ID for audit purposes).  This has many entities.

**What I Did:**

Now let's pretend I spend a few days doing some domain-level development.  I add handful of classes, set up their db counterparts, build the models (in `CoreContext`, `MembershipContext` doesn't change), write integration tests for the models and unit tests for the domain work.  All is well.  I haven't touched `MembershipContext` at all.

Part of what I did was add a new class to `LPA.Domain` to deal with an object called Matter (legal matter).  This was to mock up a single method I needed elsewhere, but was not set up in the db (yet).  I added an `Ignore()` on the appropriate entity and will flesh it out later.  No biggie, right?  All still happening in the `CoreContext`

**What Happened:**

I get done with a few days of domain-level development, then go to fire up the LPA.Web project and hit a strange error when trying to log in.  Some digging around tells me basically this:

When trying to get from `Users` in `MembershipContext`, it's throwing an exception saying that the `LPA.Data.Matter` EntityType has no key.

A couple confusing things about this:

1. `LPA.Data.Matter` is not an object.  The `Matter` object resides in the `LPA.Domain.Legal` namespace.  Presumably this is an internal thing with EF6 as it creates it's own object to deal with things.  Ok, I can buy that...
2. `MembershipContext` makes no use of `Matter` at all.  The three objects it does make use of have no downstream references (shallow or deep) to the `Matter` object.
3. **Integration Testing to build/retrieve the `MembershipContext.Users` works fine!** (Users being the offending Entity in the exception)  I think this must indicate some different method between how the `LPA.Web` project is loading the `LPA.Data.MembershipContext` as opposed to how the test project is, but that doesn't make much sense to me...
4. This `Matter` object is used in testing for the domain project and the `LPA.Data.CoreContext` tests without issue, why does it fail on the Membership and only when using it through an MVC project?

**How I Fixed It:**

As noted, I added the `Matter` class as a quick helper on the domain but hadn't fleshed out the storage stuff yet.  As such, I had no ID field on the object.  The resolution was as simple as adding an ID field.

This resolves the problem, but does not in any way help me understand what went wrong.

For what it's worth, in the MVC project we use a custom user and role provider based on the `ExtendedMembershipProvider`, which uses a custom repository (that in turn uses the `MembershipContext`).  The instantiation of the `MembershipContext` is identical between the test and the MVC projects.  I can't imagine why they'd act differently.

It's as if something in the MVC project is forcing EF6 to read/validate every object in the Domain class to ensure their validity to a non-existing data model.

Does anyone have the slightest idea why this happened?  I'm baffled, myself.